# react i18next problem with changing language by changing path ( /en or /otherLanguage ). And home page path turn into https://en

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next, react-tsx

The language switching is working. But when I try to change the language by changing the path ( /en or /th (Thai)) it does nothing, the language is still the language selected in the menu.

And other page can handle the language switching fine, but when I try to switch language in homepage, the url got deleted and show just https://en or https://th if select the English or Thai language in the home page.

this is my main.tsx code

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import ScrollToTop from './components/utils/ScrollToTop.tsx'

import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend'

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'th'],
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    detection: {
      order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie'],
    },
    backend: {
      // loadPath: '/asset/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
      loadPath: '/asset/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
    },
  })

const loadingMarkup = (
  <div className="py-4 text-center">
    <h3>Loading..</h3>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback={loadingMarkup}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ScrollToTop />
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

In the detection, I already put the 'path' first, but it still doesn’t work

this is the App.tsx code

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer'
import FooterSmall from './components/Footer/FooterSmall'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import NavbarSmall from './components/Navbar/NavbarSmall'
import Home from './pages/Home/Home'
import AboutUs from './pages/AboutUs/AboutUs'
import DoctorAndStaff from './pages/DoctorAndStaff/DoctorAndStaff'
import ContactUs from './pages/ContactUs/ContactUs'
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'
import Service from './pages/Service/Service'
import BeforeAfter from './pages/BeforeAfter/BeforeAfter'
import Facility from './pages/Facility/Facility'
import ServiceDetail from './pages/Service/ServiceDetail'
import FacilityViewMore from './pages/Facility/FacilityViewMore'


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* nav */}
      <div className="hidden xl:block">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <div className="block xl:hidden">
        <NavbarSmall />
      </div>

      <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />

      {/* pages */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        {/* <Route path="//:lang" element={<Home />} /> */}

        <Route path="/aboutus" element={<AboutUs />} />
        <Route path="/aboutus/:lang" element={<AboutUs />} />
        {/* <Route path={`/aboutus/${'en' || 'th'}`} element={<AboutUs />} /> */}

        {/* service */}
        <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
        <Route path="/service/:id" element={<ServiceDetail />} />
        {/*  */}

        {/* facility */}
        <Route path="/facility" element={<Facility />} />
        <Route path="/facility/:id" element={<FacilityViewMore />} />
        {/*  */}
      </Routes>

      {/* footer */}
      <div className="hidden xl:block">
        <Footer />
      </div>
      <div className="block xl:hidden">
        <FooterSmall />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

I have been try on the /aboutus page. If I doesn’t put "/aboutus/:lang", it won’t work.

this is my Navbar component code, where the language switcher in

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment */
// @ts-nocheck

import th from '../../../public/Navbar/th.svg'
import en from '../../../public/Navbar/en.png'
import ReactSelect from 'react-select'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import cookies from 'js-cookie'

const langs = [
  { id: 1, lang: 'en', langName: 'EN', pic: en },
  { id: 2, lang: 'th', langName: 'TH', pic: th },
]

function Navbar() {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation()
  const location = useLocation()

  const [selectedLang, setSelectedLang] = useState(cookies.get('selectedLang') || 'en')

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the language setting whenever selectedLang changes
    i18n.changeLanguage(selectedLang)
    cookies.set('selectedLang', selectedLang)

    console.log(selectedLang)
    console.log(location.pathname)
  }, [selectedLang, i18n])

  const customStyles = {
    control: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      background: 'none',
      display: 'flex',
      border: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0,

      boxShadow: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0,
      '&:hover': {
        border: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0,
        cursor: 'pointer',
      },
    }),
  }

  const langOptions = langs.map((lang) => ({
    value: lang.lang,
    label: lang.langName,
  }))

  const formatOptionLabel = ({ value, label, isSelected }) => (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      {isSelected ? null : (
        <img
          src={langs.find((lang) => lang.lang === value)?.pic}
          alt={value}
          style={{ marginRight: '8px', width: '24px', height: '24px' }}
        />
      )}
      {label}
    </div>
  )

  const handleLangChange = (selectedOption) => {
    const langValue = selectedOption.value
    setSelectedLang(langValue)

    //to not make the /en or /th stacking after each select
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let currentPath = location.pathname.replace(/\/(en|th)$/, '')

    window.location.href = `${currentPath}/${langValue}`
  }

  return (
            <div className="flex">
              <ReactSelect
                components={{ DropdownIndicator: () => null, IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
                value={langOptions.find((option) => option.value === selectedLang)}
                onChange={handleLangChange}
                options={langOptions}
                formatOptionLabel={formatOptionLabel}
                // unstyled
                styles={customStyles}
                isSearchable={false}
              />
            </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

if I delete the `let currentPath = location.pathname.replace(/\/(en|th)$/, '')` and `window.location.href =` ${currentPath}/${langValue}`` , the home page url problem (url turn into just https://en from http://localhost:5173/) is gone. so the main problem is how do I change language by changing the path, like http://localhost:5173/en or http://localhost:5173/th to change to English and Thai language ?